# PayPal Pay Later - Empty Iframe

Tags: paypal

I've been trying to add the PayPal pay later banner to a website and unfortunately I'm getting an issue after following the documentation here:

https://www.paypal.com/ppcredit/messaging/code?layout=text&logo-type=inline&text-color=black

The PayPal script is being brought in as the  is being replaced with additional content. However no banner is being shown on the site. I've even tried creating a very basic html WebPage with just the banner is but all I'm seeing is a blank page. Inspecting the page does show some extra content but no messaging.

The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Paypal</title>
        <script
                src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AfGBtA5DGojV1CnZgZ-tOUIoL2bimSLUzHWjSPG_5RpJypzFWhG3d6FDKZI3otUGbsn_l923gwLBOIWA&currency=GBP&components=messages"
                data-namespace="PayPalSDK">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div
            data-pp-message
            data-pp-style-layout="text"
            data-pp-style-logo-type="inline"
            data-pp-style-text-color="black"
            data-pp-amount="89.99">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell this is exactly what the documentation requires and I'm at a loss to why this isn't working. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For GBP Pay Later messaging, verify you are using the [app client ID](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for a UK account of type **BUSINESS**.

If it is sandbox, see: [sandbox accounts](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've checked the Account type in PayPal and it's definitely set to business. If I go into the account it states: "Current account type: Business" which I assume is correct.

Comment: Testing the client id `AfGBtA5DGojV1CnZgZ-tOUIoL2bimSLUzHWjSPG_5RpJypzFWhG3d6FDKZI3otUGbsn_l923gwLBOIWA`  via https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , it appears to be sending payments to `sb-esfeq11978734@personal.example.com` -- note the personal